# How to canonically delete Paragraphs?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

Drupal 8, Paragraphs Version: 8.x-1.12, ERR Version: 8.x-1.8

I created a custom paragraph type. I then added a field on a node type that referenced that custom paragraph. Adding the paragraph and saving it in that nodes edit form works great. When I click 'remove' or, after, 'confirm removal' not only is it not removed from the database, no delete or pre-delete hooks are run. If the node edit form is reloaded, the paragraph is back with  the values it had before 'remove' or 'confirm removal'. If i remove and confirm removal and save the node, again, no delete or predelete hooks are run, but if the node edit form is reloaded, the paragraph appears removed. However, it still exists in the paragraphs_items_field_data table. If i just delete the entire node, the paragraph still exists in paragraphs_items_field_data.

What is the reason for this behavior? Is it because you could still restore an old revision of the node after deletion?

How do I canonically delete a Paragraph? Can it only be done programmatically?

Comment: Do you have revision on on the node type where you added the paragraph first? Did you run cron after deleting it for garbage collection?

Comment: The node type can be saved as a draft yes. Your comment triggered me to go find OrphanPurger in entity_reference_revisions. I assume this is the class that manages full deletes? It appears when ->delete() is called on an EntityReferenceRevisionsItem is when its added to the queue. When does this get called relative to Paragraphs? I don't see anything in /paragraphs/ that extends EntityReferenceRevisionsItem. Is it when 'confirm removal' is pressed or 'confirm removal' + submit?

Comment: Is it possible to detect when OrphanPurger runs and execute some code?